# Unable to convert java date object to angular string format

Tags: angular, date, date-format

I have saved java date object in `JSON` format in db as **tue dec 31 00:00:00 SGT 2019**
I want to convert this in Angular dd/MM/yyyy format.

I am using date pipe but it is giving invalid date pipe argument.

Please suggest any method to use that I can use to convert Angular side not in Java.

Below is the code i am tried for converting in Angular.

```
Public pipe=new Datepipe (‘en-US’);
this.newVal= this.pipe.transform(this.newVal,”dd/MM/yyyy”);
```

Comment: Hi Neelima and welcome, do you mind showing us your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the date from backend is always in the expected format, you could just hardcode the format for conversion

```
this.newVal = "tue dec 31 00:00:00 SGT 2019";
let temp = date.split(' ');

Public pipe=new Datepipe (‘en-US’);
this.newVal = pipe.transform(temp[5] +" " +temp[1]+" "+temp[2], "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

The amParse pipe that exists in ngx-moment is a good candidate for this.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-moment#amparse-pipe

> Parses a custom-formatted date into a moment object that can be used with the other pipes.

The output of that pipe behaves pretty much like a date and can also be used with other pipes to output it as a specific format like you're looking to do.
If you only want it in code and not in HTML, you can use some of the functions in the underlying moment.js library: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/